# What does model.setTable() really do in pyqt5

Tags: python, database, sqlite, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm confused about what setTable() method does to a QSqlTableModel. i know that it kind of tells the model which table of the database it needs to work with but i'm facing 2 issues here that make me puzzled.

Let's say i've created a foem which takes user inputs and creates a database and adds rows in it, also there os an option for removing a row and showing the entire database

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
from form import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showInfo()

        self.ui.pushButton_AddPatient.clicked.connect(self.create)

        self.ui.pushButton_DeletePatient.clicked.connect(self.deleteinfo)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.search(self.ui.lineEdit.text()))

        self.ui.pushButton_ShowPAtient.clicked.connect(self.showall)
        self.show()



    def create(self):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('patients.db')
        db.open()
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_(

           # SQL QUERY TO CREATE THE TABLE
        )
        query.exec_(

        #SQL QUERY TO INSERT SOME ROWS TO THE DATABASE
        )

        self.model.select()


   def showall(self):
        self.model.setTable("patients")

        self.model.select()


    def showInfo(self):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('patients.db')
        db.open()
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()

        self.model.setTable('patients')

        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.tableView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.ui.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows)


        self.model.select()

    def deleteinfo(self):

        #self.model.setTable("patients")
        current = self.ui.tableView.selectedIndexes()

        for item in current:
              self.model.removeRow(item.row())
        self.model.select()

    def search(self, item):
        self.model.setFilter("name LIKE '%{}%'".format(item))
        self.model.select()
```

My question is that, why do i have to include the `self.model.setTable()` statement in my `showall()` function(or else it won't work) while adding it to `deleteinfo()` causes malfunction and the program wont delete the selected row.
What if i needed to create other slots that modify the database using the Model? do i need to use `self.model.setTable()` every time or not?

Comment: I don't understand your logic, in your code you execute "showInfo" that loads the table, but on the other hand the "create" method seems to want to create a table that already exists. Does that have logic for you?

Comment: I intend to fill the table with data each time the applocation runs that's why i executed "showinfo", also in the "create" function. I use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` query along with an insertion query.

Comment: 1) If you already loaded the table in "showInfo" that implies that the table exists, why is it necessary to create a table that already exists? I don't see any sense, 2) If you are going to add rows to the table then it is better to use the table's QRecord instead of QSqlQuery.

Comment: So what i'd better do is create the table in a  seperate method and execute it, right? And for adding new rows why should i not use the insertion SQL querries?

Comment: Because it reduces time and resources, when adding rows through the table it is also used internally to QSqlQuery but in addition to this the table is notified that there is a new row, however if the table is not used then you have to reset the table (unnecessarily set the table name again) to remove the cache.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, Yes the database file already exists in my case. I wanted the user to be able to create the database when he opens the application for the first time. i omitted the create statement a build a package, the database file is there but it say it's already in use! Now about self.model.setTable() does it need to be called every time i press the button to show the entire database?